# What is the correct syllabification for this word, and what is the authoritative source for syllabification?

Tags: syllables

What is the correct syllabification of the word "eliminate"?

What is the Authoritative Source for syllabification?

Just in case it is needed, the word is used in the sentence:

> To allow more ef|fi|cient usage of paper, more reg|u|lar ap|pear|ance
>   of right-side mar|gins with|out re|quir|ing spac|ing ad|just|ments,
>   and to elim|i|nate the need to erase hand-writ|ten long words begun
>   near the end of a line that do not fit, words may be di|vided at the
>   near|est break|point be|tween syl|la|bles and a hy|phen in|serted to
>   in|di|cate that the let|ters form a word frag|ment, not a word.

from a test case on the automatic hyphenation tool found [here][3]

Sorry if my question is too simple, English is not my first language.

Comment: The dictionaries you refer to are showing the way the word is pronounced. I'd go with the AHDEL (or Collins or Webster's) version; you need to get to know how their pronunciation indications work, or better, hear the word pronounced correctly.

Comment: Maybe my question is wrong. I'm actually looking for the syllable division of the word. I'm not sure if it is equivalent to the hyphenation.

Comment: When hyphenating, you usually want to avoid stranding single letters on a line. There's also some consideration given to avoiding misleading fragments at the end of a line.

Comment: Syllable division and hyphenation aren't quite the same, for the reason I mention above. Best to clarify the question. (Asking about syllabification might be too simple, but you could easily make the question interesting by asking about the difference between syllables and hyphenation. Or asking about dictionary notation.)

Comment: Yes, sorry. I rewrote the question to be about syllabification, as that is what I need. If I understand correctly, the answer would be "the authoritative source is any dictionary, each having its notation to indicate syllabification"

Comment: If you want an authoritative source for hyphenation (which is what your program is giving you), you can look at the [Oxford Dictionary Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/eliminate?q=eliminate) for British English. It gives *elim|in|ate*. You can look at [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eliminate) for American hyphenation. It gives *elim|i|nate*.

Comment: RE; my previus comment. The *Oxford Dictionary Online* is now *Lexico*, and it appears that it no longer gives divisions into syllables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an inherent problem with your question:

1. There is no authority that decides the [syllabification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllabification) of any words.  (Or anything else in the English language for that matter.)
2. Syllabification differs from pronunciation in English (which can vary by accent), making it challenging to decide the natural point to break a word.

For example:

In the Northeastern United States:  El-im-in-ate or E-lim-in-ate. (Both without a strong stress on any one syllable.)

In the Southern United States:  E-lim-in-ate would be the norm.  And the accent would be strongly on the first syllable (possibly with a long E).

Neither of these pronunciations determines the proper way to syllabify the word.  Rather you would do so on the basis of the orthography and morphemes of the word itself.

If you are merely looking to break words at the end of lines for paper conservation, modern word processing has largely eliminated the need to do so.  Spacing and kerning have overtaken syllabification as the preferred method.

Comment: I actually need to determine the proper way to syllabify a word, not to break words at the end of lines. Your answer, however, gives me much insight.

Comment: There ***is*** a *de facto* authority that defines the syllabification of words. It's the dictionary. (For American English, either [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/) or [American Heritage](https://ahdictionary.com/)

Comment: @PeterShor Were that the case, half the country would be pronouncing things incorrectly based upon regional accent. I agree that the dictionary suggests, but it's not authoritative like in some countries.

Comment: @DavidM:Despite the Académie Française, France also has regional accents. And unless somebody is an expert on phonetics, they should look in a dictionary. That will probably give a much more accurate answer than doing it themself.

Comment: @PeterShor I don't disagree. I am just saying that there's no authority.